# Twilio Studio: send response message based on incoming message content

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I already have a Twilio application with this use case :

1. The incoming message is forwarded to a client
2. The client replies to the message by sending a message to the twilio number. The message body will contain the phone number at the beginning followed by the message content.
3. The web hook checks if the message is received from the client and it contains a phone number. If so, it forwards the message to the phone number in the body.

I would like to implement this use case using Twilio studio.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which part of that do you want to do with Studio? That's a few flows there. What have you tried so far and what are you stuck with?

Comment: I know we can use send message widget for Point 1. I am stuck with Point 1 and Point 2 on how to write the logic.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Split widget and use a regular expression to test whether the input from Step 2 contains a phone number or not.